# jQuery cycle page with links

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using the cycle plugin with pager functionality like this :

```
$j('#homebox') 
.cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'fast',
        timeout: 9000,
        pager:  '#home-thumbs',
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            // return sel string for existing anchor
            return '#home-thumbs li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
        }
    });
```

I was wondering how I could also add an onclick function where if the thumbs were clicked they would take you to the appropriate url.  The code comes from here:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager3.html

Comment: what do you mean take you to appropriate URL? What would be the purpose of the control then?

Comment: I think you might have to be looking at modifying the plugin... http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js

Comment: the control is still switching a graphic on mouse over, but when you click on the thumb I would like it to take the user to a new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by adding an onclick event directly to each of the thumbs.